# a custom JS and CSS for slider works only for "admin" , i need it to work for all users (public users + admin)

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have added custom JS and CSS files for adding a slider but it works correctly for me only (Admin) not for public users.i added them via a custom script plugin. here is the JS and CSS codes.

**i want it to be for all users**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){
      jQuery(".post_slide .elementor-container ").addClass("swiper-container");
  jQuery(".post_slide .elementor-row ").addClass("swiper-wrapper");
    jQuery(".post_slide .elementor-column").addClass("swiper-slide");
  jQuery('.swiper-container').append('<div class="swiper-pagination"></div><div class="swiper-button-prev"></div><div class="swiper-button-next"></div>'); 
  
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
          spaceBetween: 0,
           slidesPerView: 1,
       speed: 400,
           autoplay:true,
          breakpoints: {
            
            640: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 0,
            },
            768: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 0,
            },
            1024: {
              slidesPerView: 1,
              spaceBetween: 0,
            },
          },
                 
          navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
          },
    
        });
  
  });
```

```css
.swiper-wrapper {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-wrap: inherit;
  }
```

Comment: did you clear cache after you made it? is the script not comming out to the public at all? do you have anny console errors?

Comment: I think the important part is how this plugin is adding them. Because if the code it's working for you, maybe the problem is that the script is completely missing for the public. Inspect the source code of your page and let us know!

Comment: @Diego yes it is missing for public  , the settings for my plugin are                      Linking type=> Internal
Where on page => Header
  
Where in site => In Frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have changed the Custom file sittings :

- Where on page => Footer

now it works !!

Comment: It was most likely a caching problem then. The location of the slider like this wouldn’t be related to whether you’re logged in or not. This change probably triggered the page to change and get reloaded from the server instead of the cache.