# How to fix JS addEventList in Elementor WordPress?

Tags: javascript

When I'm trying to add script to Elementor via "HTML Edit" element from Elementor, or in any field of Elementor when edit it's HTML, addEventListener doesn't work out of admin. So if you load edited page as admin, it's work, if you join as a guest sends error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addEventListener')". All elements are available, tried everything, doesn't work. Any options to add script?

```
 function count() {
    let percent = Math.round(Number(document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[2].value)/100*35+Number(document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[2].value));
    document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[3].value = percent ;
    document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[4].value = Math.round(percent*1.35);
}
document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[2].addEventListener("input", count);
```

Comment: You can use `console.log(document.querySelectorAll(".form-control")[2])` to see if that element can be found. If not, your script probably executes before the whole `body` is loaded.

Comment: Already did, error that can't be found. But script runs after body and also if you're an admin it's work. Tried to run script after page load, tried with plugins to add script in footer, added script right after form-control block, etc., it's should start after, but doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [a custom JS and CSS for slider works only for "admin" , i need it to work for all users (public users + admin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63915204/a-custom-js-and-css-for-slider-works-only-for-admin-i-need-it-to-work-for-al)

Comment: (basically, could be a caching problem)

Comment: @GrafiCode I don't understand where this guy found custom file and other stuff he made, so no. If you know how to fix it, explain in detail

Answer (score 0):

[How to wait until an element exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525071/how-to-wait-until-an-element-exists)
+
On admin panel there's an extra input, so I've got wrong values when not as admin and searched with querySelectorAll

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I fixed mine by adding

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => { // your code });
```

before my entire javascript code.

Found my solution [here](https://forum.freecodecamp.org/t/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-addeventlistener/500603).